# Reevaluate Nuxt.js middleware without a route change

Tags: vue.js, redirect, nuxt.js, vuex, middleware

I'm wondering if it's possible to essentially "reevaluate" the middleware conditions without actually changing the current route.

The middleware's purpose is to prevent non-logged-in users from accessing the "dashboard".
My issue is, a user could become logged in or logged out without necessarily changing route but they wouldn't be redirected until they try and change pages.

I have a VueX action that triggers when the user's auth state changes but this (from what I can see), can't access the redirect or route variables.

```js
// /mixins/auth.js
const reevaluateAuthStatus = (store, redirect, route) => {
  console.log(route)
  const redirectPolicy = route.meta.map((meta) => {
    if (meta.auth && typeof meta.auth.redirectPolicy !== 'undefined') { return meta.auth.redirectPolicy[0] }
    return []
  })

  const user = store.getters['auth/getUser']
  if (redirectPolicy.includes('LOGGEDOUT')) {
    if (user) {
      return redirect('/dashboard')
    }
  } else if (redirectPolicy.includes('LOGGEDIN')) {
    if (!user) {
      return redirect('/login')
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  reevaluateAuthStatus
}
```

```js
// /middleware/auth.js
import { reevaluateAuthStatus } from '../mixins/auth'

export default function ({ store, redirect, route }) {
  reevaluateAuthStatus(store, redirect, route)
}
```

Appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-evaluate a middleware AFAIK because it's mainly this (as stated in [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware#middleware-directory))

> middlewares will be called [...] on the client-side when navigating to further routes

2 clean ways you can still achieve this IMO:

- use some websockets, either with [socket.io](https://socket.io/) or something similar like [Apollo Subscriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/), to have your UI taking into account the new changes
- export your middleware logic to some kind of call, that you could trigger again by [calling the `$fetch` hook again](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/fetch#the-fetch-hook) or any other [data-related fetching hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/$nuxt#refreshing-page-data) in Nuxt

Some more ugly solutions would probably be:

- making an internal [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) and check if the actual state is still valid every 5s or so
- move to the same page you are actually on with something like `this.$router.go(0)` as somehow explained in the [Vue router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n)

Still, most of the cases I don't think that this one may be a big issue if the user is logged out, because he will just be redirected once he tries something.
As if the user becomes logged-in, I'm not even sure on which case this one can happen if he is not doing something pro-active on your SPA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's relevant or not, but I solved a similar problem this way:

- I have a global middleware to check the auth status. It's a function that receives Context as a parameter.
- I have a plugin that injects itself into context (e.g. $middleware).
  The middleware function is imported here.
- In this plugin I define a method that calls this middleware passing the context (since the Plugin has Context as parameter as well): `ctx.$middleware.triggerMiddleware = () => middleware(ctx);`
- Now the middleware triggers on every route change as intended, but I can also call `this.$middleware.triggerMiddleware()` everywhere I want.